# Method on class [] was used outside of a Grails application

Tags: grails, groovy, static-members

Previous questions on this error refer to a hibernate version issue or running a test.  I do not think this is the case here.

In a Grails Service class I have:

```
private static User anon = User.findByUsername('anonymous')
```

and this is creating the error:

```
Caused by IllegalStateException: Method on class [User] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
```

I am trying to instantiate a private static attribute with an object stored in the database, but I must be doing something terribly wrong.  Thanks for any help, suggestions and pointers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't work to make this `static`, because that will try and make the `findByUsername` call at the point when the service *class* is loaded, which is before the `GrailsApplication` initialization procedure is complete.  The earliest you can reliably call GORM methods is at `BootStrap` time, so what I tend to do in these sorts of situations is create an initialization method on the service and then call that method from the `BootStrap` init closure.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but, which version of grails were you using? I had the same problem after a migration from grails 2.3 to grails 2.5.

After some pretty painful investigation, I found out that problem is when running tests with new fork mode properties, and is easy to solve by removing these options from BuildConfig.groovy:

```
 grails.project.fork = [
        // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
        //compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

        // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
        test: false,
        // configure settings for the run-app JVM
        run: [maxMemory: 1536, minMemory: 512, debug: false, maxPerm: 1024, forkReserve:false],
        // configure settings for the run-war JVM
        war: [maxMemory: 1536, minMemory: 512, debug: false, maxPerm: 1024, forkReserve:false],
        // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
        console: [maxMemory: 1536, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 1024]
]
```

Regards.